# SQL to display both month and year between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have four variables CurrentMonth, CurrentYear, Month, year. I want to have a SQL statement which displays all the months and years between (Month,Year) to (currentMonth,CurrentYear). The below displays months but I need months and year and I dont have dates but only month and year of start and End.

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);
```

Comment: My question is not between the dates but between 2 years and Months

Comment: The solution in the duplicate will work, you just have to rework it.`Hint` - change the `day` to `month/year`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a modification from the previous answer from indicently to meet your Month/Year needs.

```
    DECLARE @FromMonth varchar(2), @FromYear varchar(4), @ToMonth as Varchar(2), @ToYear as varchar(4)
    SET @FromMonth = '01';
    SET @FromYear = '1944';
    SET @ToMonth = '04';
    SET @ToYear = '1956';


    DECLARE @DateFrom smalldatetime, @DateTo smalldatetime;
    SET @DateFrom=@FromYear+@FromMonth+'01';
    SET @DateTo=@ToYear+@ToMonth+'01';
    -------------------------------
    WITH T(date)
    AS
    ( 
    SELECT @DateFrom 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(month,1,T.date) FROM T WHERE T.date < @DateTo
    )

    SELECT  datename(m,date) + '-' + datename(yy,date) as DN FROM T 
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```