# SQL Show Number of Months and Years Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table that shows the start date and the end date for a product. I have the total value and the product name in the table. I would like to be able to show the months and years between the two dates while including the product name and the average of the value over the time period. I have been trying to work with a query that solves the issue for a single product. I need the result to show across multiple products. I'm getting an error saying that I cannot query more than one item in the sub query. Is it possible to get the result I'm looking for? Thank you for your help. It’s greatly appreciated.

[SQL to display both month and year between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412572/sql-to-display-both-month-and-year-between-two-dates)

Example of Product Data

```
    Product    Value Start Date End Date
    Widget A    100 1/1/2012    5/1/2013
    Widget B    500 2/1/2010    6/1/2012
```

Desired Results

```
    Product     Date       Month Year    Value
    Widget A    1/1/2012    Jan 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    2/1/2012    Feb 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    3/1/2012    Mar 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    4/1/2012    Apr 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    5/1/2012    May 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    6/1/2012    Jun 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    7/1/2012    Jul 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    8/1/2012    Aug 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    9/1/2012    Sep 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    10/1/2012   Oct 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    11/1/2012   Nov 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    12/1/2012   Dec 2012     5.88 
    Widget A    1/1/2013    Jan 2013     5.88 
    Widget A    2/1/2013    Feb 2013     5.88 
    Widget A    3/1/2013    Mar 2013     5.88 
    Widget A    4/1/2013    Apr 2013     5.88 
    Widget A    5/1/2013    May 2013     5.88 
    Widget B    2/1/2010    Feb 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    3/1/2010    Mar 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    4/1/2010    Apr 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    5/1/2010    May 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    6/1/2010    Jun 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    7/1/2010    Jul 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    8/1/2010    Aug 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    9/1/2010    Sep 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    10/1/2010   Oct 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    11/1/2010   Nov 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    12/1/2010   Dec 2010     17.24 
    Widget B    1/1/2011    Jan 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    2/1/2011    Feb 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    3/1/2011    Mar 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    4/1/2011    Apr 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    5/1/2011    May 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    6/1/2011    Jun 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    7/1/2011    Jul 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    8/1/2011    Aug 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    9/1/2011    Sep 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    10/1/2011   Oct 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    11/1/2011   Nov 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    12/1/2011   Dec 2011     17.24 
    Widget B    1/1/2012    Jan 2012     17.24 
    Widget B    2/1/2012    Feb 2012     17.24 
    Widget B    3/1/2012    Mar 2012     17.24 
    Widget B    4/1/2012    Apr 2012     17.24 
    Widget B    5/1/2012    May 2012     17.24 
    Widget B    6/1/2012    Jun 2012     17.24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one, get a list of dates.  The monthly dates in your output *have to come from somewhere*...that's how SQL works.  Creating and maintaining a "calendar table" is very common, but there are other ways too.

```
CREATE TABLE months ([Date] date)
--Populate table with a list of first-of-months

SELECT
  p.[Product],
  m.[Date],
  LEFT(DATENAME(month,m.[Date]),3) AS [Month]
  YEAR(m.[Date]) AS [Year]
  p.[Value]/(DATEDIFF(month,p.[Start Date],p.[End Date])+1) AS [Value]
FROM months m
INNER JOIN products p ON (m.[Date] BETWEEN p.[Start Date] AND p.[End Date])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross join to a numbers/dates table.

If you don't have one however they are relatively inexpensive to create on the fly using a system table and `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
WITH Product AS
(   SELECT  Product, 
            Value = CAST(Value AS DECIMAL(10, 2)), 
            StartDate = CAST(StartDate AS DATE), 
            EndDate = CAST(EndDate AS DATE)
    FROM    (VALUES
                ('Widget A', 100, '20120101', '20130501'),
                ('Widget b', 500, '20100201', '20120601')
            ) t (Product, Value, StartDate, EndDate)
), Numbers AS
(   SELECT  Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
)
SELECT  p.Product,
        d.[Date],
        MonthYear = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, d.[Date]), 3) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, d.[Date]), 
        Value = CAST(p.Value / (1 + DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.StartDate, p.EndDate)) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
FROM    Product p
        CROSS JOIN Numbers n
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT Date = DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, p.StartDate)) d
WHERE   d.[Date] <= p.EndDate
ORDER BY p.Product, [Date];
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29224)**

For some further reading on generating and using a numbers/dates table, both static and on the fly, take a look at this series:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)